# passing date from vb.net to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

i want to pass date from my vb.net to mysql . 
in mysql i have selected datatype as date. 
plz help me how to pass from datetime picker.
my format in vb.net is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: If you run in debug mode, it will tell you exactly which line the error is

Comment: A `DateTime` format is not relevant. Use the `DateTimePicker.Value`.

Comment: Can you use parameterized queries? I think they should solve formatting issues in .NET.

Comment: The mysql date format is "yyyy-MM-dd", So if you format a datetime picker you should use this: `format(datetimepicker1.value, "yyyy-MM-dd")`. hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Do as suggested by @jimi in comments

```
Private Sub TestMySql()
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.dbusersConnection)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Update dbusers Set myDate = @Date Where myuser = @Name", cn)                
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "joe"
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

If you send a DateTime to the database and the database data type is Date, it doesn't matter how you format. It is not a String. It is a Date. The provider and ADO will sort it out so MySql is happy.

Comment: The downvote is probably caused by the quality of question itself. Anyway, a couple of notes: `MySqlDbType.Date` and `MySqlDbType.DateTime` are [two different types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDbType.htm). Using `MySqlDbType.Date`, you should pass `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date`. The parameters are out of order. One may say that it (probably) doesn't matter. Another one may not know when it matters and when it doesn't. So, better have them in order all the time (my opinion :)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback. I tested that Date with DateTime and it worked with my MySql. I agree about the both your corrections. .Date would be better to avoid confusion. Same with the order or parameters.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL uses the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

You can format your date so MySQL likes it:

```
MyDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

[Here you can find more "time and date" formatting informations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Y200)

Have fun!