# how do I correct my date time value when taking an input from a text box and inserting it into mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I keep getting this error from visual studio when I insert a date value into my database

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Incorrect datetime value: '0014-04-2021''

I changed my DateTime picker format to short so that it doesn't include the time when it takes the value from the DateTime picker but the problem still persists.

this is my SQL query code

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into inventory.vehicle(regdate) values(@regdate)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@regdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datereg.Text;

int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Instead of pass the value with `string` type, pass the value with `DateTime` type will able to solve the problem. You may refer to the answer for [Parse Date to MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55108390/8017690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your column declared as a DATE type in MySQL

Then use `.Date` on the datetimepicker's `.Value`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@regdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datereg.Value.Date;
```

You should note that this does not "remove" a time from a date; it sets it to midnight. There is no way to remove a time from a date- a moment in time is a moment in time, just like 1 and 1.0 are the same thing. 1 might be formatted without any decimal digits but it's illogical to say that 1 and 1.0 are different

Once you make all your dates have the same time (midnight, 00:00:00 which is effectively the .0 in 1.0) the ability to compare datetimes in date alone makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try to use simple `<input type="date">`, because it has default format to YYYY-MM-DD